# setiosflags(ios::showbase) -> Why do I need to write ios?

Tags: c++, std

In c++ manipulator `setiosflags(ios::showbase)` what does `ios` do here? Well, I did some research and got to know that it is related to the input and output job but if I have already included the header file `<iostream>` why do I need to include `<ios>` or even write `ios::showbase`? Can't I just write `setiosflags(showbase)`. Please explain I don't understand a thing.

Answer (score 2):

`showbase` is a member of [`std::ios_base`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags) so you need to use `std::ios_base::showbase` or you can use one of the derived classes of `std::ios_base` like `std::ios` instead.

Alternatively you can use the [manipulator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase) (which is declared in the `std` namespace) instead which is a little more concise, e.g.:

```
stream << std::showbase;
```

Comment: What is std::ios_base?

Comment: Follow the link in my answer, it's the base class of the c++ streams

Comment: I am really sorry, I didn't understand that can you explain it to me in simple terms..in an easy way.

Comment: And one more! When I try to print the octal form of the decimal number 65 , IT PRINTS OUT 65 ONLY!   Here is the code : cout<<setiosflags(ios::oct)<<65<<endl; 
 Help!

Comment: Just use [std::dec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)